# Slider navigation with connected bullets

Tags: jquery, slider

Im trying to make slider with bullets that are connected with each other by lines. These lines are to change color, when the bullet is clicked. So the question is how to disable the next bullets if the previous are clicked again? Here is the [link example](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/wKPVav).

```
$('label').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active').prev('.line-element').toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is what you want:

```
$('label').click(function() {
  if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
  {
      $(this).addClass('active').prev('.line-element').addClass("active");    
  }
  $(this).closest('.lines').nextAll('.lines').find('.line-element,label').removeClass('active');
  //Just removeClass from all the next .line-element and label when previous is clicked
});
```

**[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/vNpywm)**

Above code does not work if you directly click 3rd `label`. But below fix does.

```
$('label').click(function() {
  if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
  {
      $(this).addClass('active').prev('.line-element').addClass("active").closest('.lines').prevAll('.lines').find('.line-element,label').addClass('active');    
  }
  $(this).closest('.lines').nextAll('.lines').find('.line-element,label').removeClass('active')
});
```

**[Updated Pen 2](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/EVoZYj)**

Comment: Yeah! the second one is the solution! Thanks for a huge saving of time and extra experience.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)